# Как получить усредненные данные за час

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно получать информацию о среднем количестве строк, за каждый уникальный час по которому имеется информация.

```
Select (SELECT
  AVG(the_count) average
FROM (SELECT
  HOUR(check_at) AS the_hour,
  COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM comments,
     Users
WHERE check_at >= 1429695718
  AND check_at != FALSE
  AND comments.user = Users.Id
GROUP BY the_hour) s
GROUP BY the_hour) AS in_hour from `users`
```

Данный запрос справляется только когда существует один пользователь, как только появляется информация о еще нескольких, то получаю ошибку из php.

> General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered
>   queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll()

Насколько я понимаю ошибка заключается в том, что во внутреннем запросе возвращается больше одной строки.

upd:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Вот ошибка при прямом запросе к mysql

Comment: а что за поле `check_at` которое сначала Вы проверяете на больше числового значения и следом что оно не равно `false`

Comment: вам же почти русским языком написали: вы пытаетесь выполнить запрос, хотя у вас еще активен как-то другой. Т.е. вам надо выполнить [PDOStatement::closeCursor()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.closecursor.php), либо сначала выбрать все записи из прошлого запроса и только потом создавать новый. И сам запрос здесь не причем, проблема в php-коде. Надо его приводить, а не запрос

Comment: @BOPOH я выполнил этот чистый запрос в mysql и мне пишет, что внутренний запрос возвращает более одной строки

Comment: @Bald56rus оно тут вообще роли не играет, забыл убрать лишнее условие просто.

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите сделать? У вас кошмар какой-то, а не запрос. Возможно, простого `count(user)/count(1)` будет достаточно? А проблема сейчас вроде в том, что в одной ячейки строки должно быть только одно значение. А у вас получается не одно, а набор строк, что и приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Цитируемая ошибка не имеет отношения к запросу, а только к PDO и скрипту.

Comment: @BOPOH, мне нужно получить среднее количество записей за каждый  час за который имеются записи и за определенный интервал.

Comment: это я читал. Но у вас выбирает среднее в час, а вы пишите - среднее по часам. Т.е. запрос выберет только одно число, но по задаче вы хотите получить все часы. И при чем здесь Users и check_at? Попробуйте убрать внешний select - тогда вроде уже валидным должен будет быть запрос.

Comment: @artoodetoo, добавил не из pdo

Comment: @BOPOH  users и check_at мне нужны, для того чтобы сделать все в одном запросе. это не один нагруженный селект в нем

Comment: @BOPOH и возможно я не так выразился, мне нужно не по отдельному часу средние, а среднее за все часы по интервалу, мне и нужно одно число

Answer (score 2):

У вас нагромождение ошибок как логических, в самом запросе, так и в организации выборки результата в PHP.

1. Первая цитируемая ошибка (про PDO) говорит о том, что вы не вычерпали данные предыдущего запроса, а уже вызываете новый. То есть *вероятно* вы читаете только одну запись там, где их вернулось несколько.
2. Подзапрос подзапросу рознь! Нельзя чтобы подзапрос во фразе SELECT возвращал более одной строки. Нормально когда это происходит в подзапросе во фразе FROM. Об этом текст второй ошибки с "more than 1 row"
3. Поле check_at у вас то ли время содержит, то ли истина/ложь, где-то в логике косяк.
4. Похоже, что под-запрос никак не использует данные из внешнего запроса, т.к. у него есть свой users и вы алиасами их не разграничили. То есть при нескольких 
   записях в users подзапрос должен тупо выдавать *одно и то же* на каждом проходе.

При таком раскладе лучше переписать всё с нуля!
Если вы будете так добры выложить минимально необходимый объем данных на http://sqlfiddle.com , мы вам найдем решение.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что так долго не отвечал. [Вот к примеру данные для двух таблиц.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47fa4)

Comment: Или вот. С упрощенным запросом выборки, без лишних условий нежели в вопросе. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6018d/1

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```sql
SELECT AVG(the_count) average
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM comments, Users
WHERE check_at >= 1429695718
  AND check_at != FALSE
  AND comments.user = Users.Id
GROUP BY HOUR(check_at)) s;
```